# how to find the records inserted for a table based on today date

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an table with  column as  timestamp value  gets  stored like this **"2010-12-18 16:36:26.363"**

the table name is  employee

As  records get inserted with time value  i am not able  to  find the records  inseted  for  today date.

Is there any way i can write an Query to find teh REcords inseted  for a particuar day.
 sothat i can get   all the records inseted  for  that day

any help would be  great.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT *
FROM <YourTable>
WHERE DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,<TimeStampColum>)) = '01 Jan 2010'
```

Or maybe something like

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    <YourTable> 
WHERE   DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,<TimeStampColum>)) = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()))
```

This calculation `DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,<TimeStampColum>))` will return the `Date` part only of a `DateTime` value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script.

```
 @ProccessDay datetime = '2010-12-20'
 @ProccessTimeMin datetime, 
 @ProccessTimeMax datetime,  


Set @ProccessTimeMin= DATEADD(s,+1,DATEADD(day , -1, @ProccessDay ))  
Set @ProccessTimeMax= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(day , +1, @ProccessDay ))  
BEGIN  

select * from table where  TimeStamp between @ProccessTimeMin and @ProccessTimeMax
```